# Custom user tracking or 3rd party service for page referral analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-analytics, mixpanel

The question I'm trying to answer for a set of users is how other users end up on their page. There are about 5 different ways a user can end up on your page. For example, they could have searched your name, clicked a link from a newsfeed or received an e-mail with a link to your page.

What is the best way to accomplish tracking these events? I'm initially inclined to create a table to track this. Each link would send an async event to the server to be added to the table. However, I'm also aware that there are many tracking services out there such as Google Analytics and Mixpanel. I've looked at their docs briefly and they don't seem to fit my need.

Am I missing something? Is it worth it to create a "custom" even tracking system to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not worth creating your own service. Plus you cannot add async link to search engine result pages or emails (that would require tracking code that you cannot implement in search engines or that would not be executed in mail clients).

Web analytics software tracks traffic sources by analyzing the incoming traffic via its http headers. If there is a referrer set the traffic will be attributed to, well, the referring site, unless the traffic is included in a list of known search engines in which case it will be attributed to organic search traffic etc.

In most systems you can customize source attribution by adding query parameters in the url (obviously this will not work with search engines and the like, since you cannot add parameters to organic search results). For example with  Google Analytics you can add [custom campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) in email links or advertising campaigns. If people click on those links the parameter value will be send to GA and the source/medium/campaign information will be set accordingly (e.g. traffic from web mail clients would usually be attributed as a referrer, but campaign parameters allow to attribute the link to your mail campaigns).

There might be reasons to create your own system, but channel attribution is not one of them; GA and every other system I know of has this thoroughly covered.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear. All of these links would be in app. A user would end up on a page from clicking a hyperlink in app, not from an external app. Both the newsfeed and search examples would be in-app, not from google search or facebook newsfeed. With google analytics I'd be able to see the results on GA webpage but I wouldn't have them in app for a user to see, unless they provide an API I can query to get stats for specific pages which I haven't seen. Does that make sense?